# Cannot use super.method() in overriden async method

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs

I wanted to do some task before and after delegating the request onto the parent method. And the `Parent.create` is implemented as an `async` function. So doing the following results in error.

```
async create(ctx, next) {
    await super.create(ctx, next); //'super' keyword unexpected here
}
```

But this works.

```
create(ctx, next) {
    super.create(ctx, next); //wait for the promise, then
}
```

All the Parent methods are bound to `this` as I need class context while being used as router handler.

How to use super in `async` function.

Comment: Which environment is this? Browser (which)? Node? Babel?

Comment: Using `babel-register`.

Comment: This seems to be an open issue. https://github.com/jhen0409/babel-preset-es2015-node6/issues/5

Comment: Had to use `transform-es2015-classes` for it to work. Thanks.